# obtaining vector length within a function using sapply

Tags: r, sapply

I am attempting to write a function that requires:

1. treating columns names as variables
2. obtaining the length of a column (or accessing the last row)
3. summing a subset of rows in a column

I can do Step 1 with `sapply`, but I am stuck on Step 2.  How can I obtain the length of the vector?  Below is an example data set.

```
my.data <- read.table(text = '
   y1970  y1980  y1990
       5      7      9
      50     70     90
     500    700    900
    5000   7000   9000
', header = TRUE, na.string='NA', stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Desired result of Step 2 is:

```
5000   7000   9000
```

Desires result of Step 3 is:

```
4445  6223  8001
```

Here is a function for Step 2:

```
my.function <- function(x) { 
     names.x <- as.character(colnames(my.data)[x])
     x2 <- my.data[[x]][length(x)]   # returns first row of my.data
     return(x2=x2)
}
sapply(1:ncol(my.data), function(x) {my.function(x)})

# possible code for Step 3 if I get Step 2 to work:
(x2 - sum(my.data[[x]][1:(length(my.data[[x]])-1)], na.rm=TRUE)
```

Perhaps `x` has `length == 1`, which would explain why the above code returns only the first row for `x2`, instead of only the last row, the row I want returned.

I can perform these operations easily outside a function, but how can I perform them inside a function that allows column names to be used as variables?  Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Mark, I think you're localising the problem too much. You should explain what you're actually trying to accomplish. We get that you've tried a lot. So I suggest you strip-off the things you've tried and explain to us the *actual problem*. Don't assume anything and don't try to get an answer on what you're currently holding. There may be better ways. I see you're trying quite a bit, but it's not working as expected... :)

Comment: The problem is that from this question as well as the other question, I find it hard to imagine what your actual problem is and where the need for list of lists is.. Are you sure there isn't another way to describe your problem?

Comment: steps 2 and 3: `tail(my.data, 1) - colSums(head(my.data, -1))`

Comment: @flodel Thanks.  I have now implemented your suggestion inside the function in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for Step 2.

```
my.function <- function(x) { 
     names.x <- as.character(colnames(my.data)[x])
     x2 <- my.data[[x]][length(my.data[[x]])]
     return(x2=x2)
}
sapply(1:ncol(my.data), function(x) {my.function(x)})

[1] 5000 7000 9000
```

Here is code for all three steps:

```
my.function <- function(x) { 
     names.x <- as.character(colnames(my.data)[x])
     x2 <- my.data[[x]][length(my.data[[x]])]
     x3 <- x2 - (sum(my.data[[x]], na.rm=TRUE) - x2)
     return(x3)
}
sapply(1:ncol(my.data), function(x) {my.function(x)})

[1] 4445 6223 8001
```

Here is code for the solution suggested by @flodel but implemented inside the function:

```
my.function <- function(x) { 
     names.x <- as.character(colnames(my.data)[x])
     x2 <- tail(my.data[[x]],1) - sum(head(my.data[[x]], -1))
     return(x2)
}
sapply(1:ncol(my.data), function(x) {my.function(x)})
```